# Reaction energy of oxygen and hydrogen

Tags: thermodynamics, bond, equation-of-state

From the bonding energy of following bonds that I found in a [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bond-dissociation_energy), I calculated the reaction energy that would be released when oxygen and hydrogen are reacted to produce water. The phase of each component is unknown.

$$
\begin{array}{lc}
\hline
\text{Bond} & D_0/\pu{kJ mol-1} \\
\hline
\ce{H-H} & 436 \\
\ce{O-H} & 497 \\
\ce{O=O} & 498 \\
\hline
\end{array}
$$

Therefore,

$$\ce{2 H2 + O2 -> 2 H2O} + \pu{618 kJ}$$

However, [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxyhydrogen#Properties) suggests that $\pu{241.8 kJ}$ of energy is released for every mole of hydrogen, which is $\pu{483.6 kJ}$ per $\pu{2 mol}$ for the context of the equation above.

Even when I consider the vaporization of water, which is $\pu{40.65 kJ mol-1}$, the total energy will amount to $\pu{536.7 kJ}$ per $\pu{2 mol}$, which is still far away from $\pu{483.6 kJ}$ per $\pu{2 mol}$ that is suggested in the Wikipedia article.

Where could this extra energy be going?

Comment: Bond energies are a great deal **less** universal than you seem to be thinking.

Comment: The catch may be the cleavage of OH in water. Also, you need to be careful with signs, vaporization is endothermic.

Comment: I am aware that it is endothermic. Therefore I have performed the following calculation:

    2H2 + O2 = 2H2O(liquid) + 618kJ = (2H2O(gas) - 40.65kJ*2) + 618kJ = 2H2O(gas) + 536.7kJ

Comment: Please tell me. If my way is unconventional, what method is normally used to solve thermochemical equations in chemistry?

Comment: @Y.Yoshii Maybe this is useful: https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/jp013909s

Comment: I cannot speak for the source of the data on the wikipedia page on oxyhydrogen which you linked. However it may matter to what T the data refers, from the wikipedia page on bond dissociation energies, "The enthalpy change is temperature dependent, and the bond-dissociation energy is often defined to be the enthalpy change of the homolysis at 0 K (absolute zero), although the enthalpy change at 298 K (standard conditions) is also a frequently encountered parameter."

Comment: Regarding temperature change: If you are to burn oxy-hydrogen and burn it with different temperatures, then does that mean you will have different energy output for those different temperatures of flames?
That sounds like to me is breaking the conservation of energy.

Comment: The enthalpy of dissociation can show a temperature dependence due to changes with temperature in the heat capacity of reagent and products. Different rovibrational states are occupied to different extents at different temperatures, altering the mean dissociation energy.

Answer (score 1):

Part of the discrepancy appears to be due to the need for two $\ce{O-H}$ dissociation energy terms to compute the $\ce{OH}$ bond energy for water: one for the $\ce{OH}$ bond in water (i.e. $\ce{H-OH}$), and another for the $\ce{OH}$ bond in the $\ce{OH}$ radical (i.e. $\ce{^.O-H}$). Values for these are reported by Ruscic et al. [[1](https://doi.org/10.1021/jp013909s)]. Using the average value of $\ce{D_0}$ for $\ce{H2O}$ (the $\ce{OH}$ bond energy for water), namely $\pu{459 kJ/mol}$, gives

$$\ce{2H2 + O2 -> 2H2O} \quad \Delta H = \pu{-466 kJ/mol}$$

This point is addressed in the Wikipedia page for "bond dissociation energy", the reference cited therein providing a slightly different bond energy for water of $\pu{461.5 kJ/mol}$.

Given various uncertainties common to the measurement of bond dissociation energies, and the potential effect of temperature on the bond energy, the final discrepancy seems reasonable.

#### References

1. Ruscic, B.; Wagner, A. F.; Harding, L. B.; Asher, R. L.; Feller, D.; Dixon, D. A.; Peterson, K. A.; Song, Y.; Qian, X.; Ng, C.-Y.; et al. On the Enthalpy of Formation of Hydroxyl Radical and Gas-Phase Bond Dissociation Energies of Water and Hydroxyl. *The Journal of Physical Chemistry A* **2002**, 106 (11), 2727–2747. https://doi.org/10.1021/jp013909s.

Comment: That is brilliant. Thank you for your information.